# vim delete parenthesis

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I have cursor at first `t` and I want to delete all this code from `t` to `};\n` without counting lines. How can I achieve it? Is there more cleaner way than <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>}</kbd><kbd>;</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>?

```
tabControl.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    ...
};
```

If it matters, this is C#.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "cleaner". You want to delete to `};`, so the search could be the good option no ?

Comment: if you have an empty line after the last line, `d}` is a good option.. else try `d][dd`

Comment: How about `4dd`?

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg I wrote "without lines counting".

Comment: @nobe4, I meant way with less keys and more universal, e.g. `Vj%d` takes only five keys and is applicable for any length of code block and for code blocks without semicolon after `}`

Comment: `Shorter` is the term then ;)

Comment: @nobe4 `Shorter` does not includes meaning "with no lines/chars count/type hardcoded " ;)

Comment: Place the cursor on the first `{` and press `d%`.  This would delete the body of the function while taking into account any nested blocks.

Comment: @Icd047 This doesn't delete first line. Read the question, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have gone for `v<down>%<right>d`, or `vj%ld` if you're allergic to cursor keys.

Thanks to `v` we can go into visual mode and from here, it looks like an interactive mode to select something on which a command will be applied.

Note: As Tumbler has indicated, you could also have used `V<down>%d` which will neatly handle the last line.

Comment: You could use `V` for whole lines. That way the last `;` gets deleted too.

Comment: Indeed, you're right.

Answer (score 7):

```
Vj%d
```

is one solution.

```
V/^};<CR>d
```

is another.

Whatever works for you, really.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>` is for deleting a block. You can also use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> for that to take effect.

In case if `;` at the end is not deleted, you can press <kbd>x</kbd> to delete that character

Comment: None of your variants work. They both delete outside block.

Comment: :O This is to delete inside a block. Can you press dd and then da{  and then x?

Comment: Of course I can. But this doesn't works with a nested block.

Answer (score 0):

A few solutions have already been mentioned and I would like to add one more that **might** help.

If there is a blank line after `};`, which I am assuming is not rare considering that its the end of a block, you can just do <kbd>`d`</kbd><kbd>`}`</kbd> and that will delete till the blank line.

But Of course this won't work if the next line starts immediately without a blank line or if there is a blank line inside the block. I hope that helped.

Comment: This doesn't works if I have an empty lines inside parenthesis. I hope, some plugin (for c#?) could fix it, but I have to try a dozen before I find it.

Comment: Yeah I know. `}` breaks on empty lines. You can probably create a text object of your own for C# if you did not find anything else.

Comment: They probably did, but I have not learned vim enough yet :)